# Website to send clients browser settings via email

Tags: browsers, clients, browser-detecting

A while ago I stumbled across a website that allowed you to enter an email address and have things like your browser type, version, build, javascript settings, flash version etc emailed through. I have a couple of clients that I need this information for and cannot really ask them to find out this information manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it [Support Details](http://supportdetails.com/)?

Comment: That sure looks like it

Comment: That's exactly right! Thanks! With a name like that you'd think I'd remember it hehe

Comment: Wow thats a really cool site. I'll have to save that